# House keeping or house cleaning?

Tags: word-choice, differences

I'm a web professional, recently we wanted to make major changes into our web app and one of our colleagues used the word `house cleaning`. What phrase do you use to say major changes need to be done.  Can we use `house keeping`? What is the difference between them?

Comment: What are the "major changes"? *Cleaning* doesn't imply a change to the house, except making it clean.

Comment: Changing the structure of the software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word *[housekeeping](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/housekeeping)* normally implies things that are done on a **regular** basis to keep things a house clean and organized -- or, in the case of a computer system or software, keep things running smoothly.

(*House cleaning* is something that a [cleaning service](http://www.mollymaid.com/why-maid/house-cleaning.aspx) does.)

To describe major changes, words like *[renovation](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/renovate#renovation)* or *[overhaul](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus/british/overhaul#overhaul_4)* would be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

*House cleaing* normally has a literal meaning, making it unsuitable for the use you have in mind. *Housekeeping* (ususally one word) is widely understood to mean maintenance, although it retains its more literal meaning of looking after a home as well.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say either of those because like the previous answers said, housekeeping is just a regular maintenance while house cleaning is nothing close to making a change. Sounds more like getting rid of things you don't need anymore.
I'd say Structural makeover or renovation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly the same, but the phrase  "to clean house" has a slang meaning of a fairly indiscriminate removal of unwanted things.  So it sort of applies, but I personally would use overhaul (completely re-do), redesign (major feature or look/feel changes), or refactor (optimize the underlying software without changing features) for what you're describing.